# Don't see div with v-if, regardless of the value in the data

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have problem with displaying component with v-if.
In one component i have `<div v-if="seen">...</div>`.
In another component I have `<button v-on:click="seen = !seen">...</button>`.
In "var vue = nev Vue({...})" file, in data: I have seen: true and this is not working.

I found "solution" which works: [example](https://codepen.io/mvaneijgen/pen/xyBbGy)
 and I tried this "function version" of data in my code, but it doesn't work too :/

Here is my code:
Main File

```
var vue = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        Navigation,
        Home,
        Footer,
        Login
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
        seen: true
        }
    },


    template: "<div><navigation></navigation><login></login><home></home><Footer></Footer></div>"

})
```

template that I can't see

```
<div v-if="seen" id="loginbox">
        <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="login" class="input is-rounded"/>
            <input type="password" placeholder="password" class="input is-rounded"/>
        </form>
    </div>
```

button template

```
 <div class="navbar-menu">
                    <div class="navbar-start"></div>
                    <div class="navbar-end">
                                <p class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" v-on:click="seen = !seen">Login</a>
                                </p>
                                <p class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link">Register</a>
                                </p>
                    </div>  
                </div>
```

I expect that when I click on button, "loginbox" template will be shown.

EDIT:
I did it in half way. I used props (used export default...) in  in template that I cannot seen. It not work properly, becouse now I can change value of "seen" only with button which is in this template. I'd like change value of it by button which is in another template.

Comment: Could you pop a [mcve] in a snippet or online editor like [this one](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) so we can play around with your code? It's unclear why this isn't working as you haven't included full templates in your question.

Comment: One thing I can see is that you're not passing your data down as props to your components so you won't be able to modify your parent component's `seen` variable.

Comment: oh, sorry.
Here you are: [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/ooj7k6wv39?fontsize=14)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should somehow share data between components.
You can do it many ways, but for this case i suggest to use event handling https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#ad

Edited your sandbox with example - https://codesandbox.io/s/mzq0r2w88j